# catch an exiting thread in c

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a thread pool. The main() function kicks off the classic pool setup. A boss thread and a few worker threads. Most of the code is completed, however the missing part is the error handling.

When an error occurs to one of the boss/worker threads, pthread_exit() is called. How does the main() thread knows that something went wrong in the pool in order to restart it?

Comment: Why don't you make your threads restart themselves rather than exiting? That sounds like a cleaner design...

Comment: @R.. that's what I thought. It's a bit more difficult in C where there are no exceptions that can be raised and caught at the outer level of the thread, but it should be possible to generate some sort of error report in the task and just loop round for another one.  I have to say that this sort of thing is much easier in C++...

Comment: No, if you're calling `pthread_exit`, then unless you're already using cancellation handlers to unwind the stack and perform cleanup tasks, you could just call `longjmp` back to where you started instead of calling `pthread_exit`. It's simply a matter of changing the `pthread_exit` call to `longjmp`. Or, you could simply call `pthread_create` before calling `pthread_exit` and make a new thread to replace the calling thread.

Comment: That sounds pretty dubious, @R..; using `longjmp()` is dangerous in and of itself, and using it instead `pthread_exit()` doesn't sound like good advice to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: If there are no cancellation handlers installed, there is absolutely no difference in behavior between calling `pthread_exit` directly and `longjmp`ing back to the initial thread entry function to call `pthread_exit`. And once you're there, you can just `goto` the beginning of the thread entry function instead of exiting. Nothing dangerous happening at all.

Comment: @R.. , how does a thread restart itself?

Comment: It can either literally start a new thread with the same start function and argument it was originally started with, or it can just jump back to the beginning of the the start function in the existing thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save error or recovery information, or you want a non-blocking function, you can use a condition variable together with an associated mutex and a structure containing the failing thread, the error and the recovery information you need. All these variables should be global.

```
pthread_cond_t cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
struct error_info err;
```

At the boss thread you must first initialize the err structure and then lock the mutex.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
```

Then you wait for a condition to occur using pthread_cond_wait.

```
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
```

After the condition occured you handle the error and you use pthread_join to get the return value from your thread. Note that pthread_cond_wait is blocking, if you want a non-blocking version you should use pthread_cond_timedwait which has a third parameter, a struct timespec *, which hold the absolute system time at which the wait expires. At the end remember to unlock your mutex.

```
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

At the failing worker thread, before exiting you should first lock the mutex, then fill the err structure, signal the boss thread, unlock the mutex and exit. To signal the boss thread you should use the pthread_cond_signal function.

```
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
pthread_join( pthread_t child, void** );
```

to get the return value of your threads. pthread_join is a blocking function that will wait for a thread to exit. You can pass the argument for pthread_join from:

```
void pthread_exit(void *value_ptr);
```